# Authentication problem in SSR mode Nuxt on laravel sanctum

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-7, laravel-sanctum

Setup is based on [Laranuxt](https://github.com/acidjazz/laranuxt) - Combination of Laravel 7 and Nuxt. Running on Windows with PHP 7.4.8

Ive been trying to authenticate a user on a nuxt application through Laravel 7 with Sanctum authenticator module. I now get a response that that seems to be OK?

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 204 No Content
```

Next i try to get user data, however i can`t because im not authorized;

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/user
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
```

However if i go over to laravel frontend after signing in within Nuxt, i am already logged in:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/home
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
```

[image]

Trying to open `http://localhost:8000/api/user` gets me in a constant loop with redirects between api/user and login ending with `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
  /*
  ** Nuxt rendering mode
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode
  */
  mode: 'universal',

    server: {
            port: process.env.PORT,
            host: process.env.HOST,
            serverUrl: process.env.API_URL
        },

        env: {
        serverUrl: process.env.API_URL
    },

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/mdi.css' },
    ],
  },
  /*
    ** Customize the progress-bar color
    */
    loading: { color: '#fff' },
    /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
    css: [],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
    plugins: [],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt/components
    '@nuxt/components',
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],

    tailwindcss: {
        configPath: '~/config/tailwind.config.js',
        cssPath: '~/assets/css/tailwind.css',
        exposeConfig: false
    },
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
  ],
  /*
  ** components module configuration
  ** See https://github.com/nuxt/components
  */
  components: true,

  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {
        baseUrl: process.env.API_URL,
    credentials: true,
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/json',
    },
  },

    auth: {
        strategies: {
        cookie: {
            cookie: {
            name: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
            }
        },
            'laravelSanctum': {
            provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
            url: process.env.API_URL
  },
        },
        redirect: {
            login: '/login',
            logout: '/login',
            callback: '/login',
            home: '/'
        }
    },

    router: {
        middleware: ['auth']
    },

  /*
  ** Build configuration
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/
  */
  build: {},
}
```

.env

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
API_URL=http://localhost:8000
AUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/auth
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=127.0.0.1:8000,127.0.0.1:3000
```

config\sanctum.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Stateful Domains
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Requests from the following domains / hosts will receive stateful API
    | authentication cookies. Typically, these should include your local
    | and production domains which access your API via a frontend SPA.
    |
    */

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', implode(',', [
    'localhost',
    'localhost:8000',
    'localhost:3000',
    '127.0.0.1',
]))),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Expiration Minutes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value controls the number of minutes until an issued token will be
    | considered expired. If this value is null, personal access tokens do
    | not expire. This won't tweak the lifetime of first-party sessions.
    |
    */

    'expiration' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When authenticating your first-party SPA with Sanctum you may need to
    | customize some of the middleware Sanctum uses while processing the
    | request. You may change the middleware listed below as required.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

config\app.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
    | framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
    | any other location as required by the application or its packages.
    |
    */

    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services the application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => (bool) env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('API_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Faker Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This locale will be used by the Faker PHP library when generating fake
    | data for your database seeds. For example, this will be used to get
    | localized telephone numbers, street address information and more.
    |
    */

    'faker_locale' => 'en_US',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Arr' => Illuminate\Support\Arr::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Http' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,

    ],

];
```

Any ideas or tips on how to receive content that requires autentication on Nuxt through Laravel API? Proxy needed maybe?

EDIT;
Checking the debug results in laravel, both laravel_session cookie and XSRF-TOKEN is matching all the way from the first login in Nuxt with "set-cookie" response from Laravel. Same cookies are also matched when executing /api/user.

Response from http://localhost:3000/auth/sanctum/csrf-cookie

```
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkE0NGpHZjdXMG42N1dJUnBtb0t3U2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieEdwWjVTMWovNTN2OFo2SFFRSjlCY1BzbW94clFJaXpFTEtXdE13THRjU0xkMTFlVDZDT21pOVJ0UG5qTXdBbSIsIm1hYyI6IjBlM2YzNDU0ZWU0ZTQ1YjhkOTZiOWQ4YWNlNDc1OTMzNTY0OWQ2M2U4NzZlMzFkM2YzNDI3YmVmOGNkMWYzOWMifQ%3D%3D; expires=Sun, 12-Jul-2020 22:13:32 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; samesite=lax
set-cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImNHR0MxdTRJMkYyenhVVmVlbnQ5eFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZWQzcEdYNXdnbUd5a3pLYTVPaGNLNG9Udnk5bGpGTTluRm01V0pzY2p1WU9pSWJkbEpmME1BREdFRDRoY3hybiIsIm1hYyI6IjJmM2FjMDU0MDIwMjk4NmMxZjNkYzIwMGFiYjhmYWM3MWFkOGI0MDRlYmZiN2YzNzIzMTQ1NzlhYTQ3ZTMzOTEifQ%3D%3D; expires=Sun, 12-Jul-2020 22:13:32 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax
```

Which then triggers http://localhost:3000/auth/login (returns statuscode 204)
Request:

```
Cookie: auth.strategy=laravelSanctum; auth._token.laravelSanctum=false; auth._token_expiration.laravelSanctum=false; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkE0NGpHZjdXMG42N1dJUnBtb0t3U2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieEdwWjVTMWovNTN2OFo2SFFRSjlCY1BzbW94clFJaXpFTEtXdE13THRjU0xkMTFlVDZDT21pOVJ0UG5qTXdBbSIsIm1hYyI6IjBlM2YzNDU0ZWU0ZTQ1YjhkOTZiOWQ4YWNlNDc1OTMzNTY0OWQ2M2U4NzZlMzFkM2YzNDI3YmVmOGNkMWYzOWMifQ%3D%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImNHR0MxdTRJMkYyenhVVmVlbnQ5eFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZWQzcEdYNXdnbUd5a3pLYTVPaGNLNG9Udnk5bGpGTTluRm01V0pzY2p1WU9pSWJkbEpmME1BREdFRDRoY3hybiIsIm1hYyI6IjJmM2FjMDU0MDIwMjk4NmMxZjNkYzIwMGFiYjhmYWM3MWFkOGI0MDRlYmZiN2YzNzIzMTQ1NzlhYTQ3ZTMzOTEifQ%3D%3D
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
```

Response:

```
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IitnbFNyUncvZzlSVUxUc0pYbU9pZWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVW8vM3RaR0d4eDRWaUc1WENUVndMK0F4K0JJdmpGcTEzNUhTcjZWTk8zb3BjQlNiVXh4d3lEVE45OWM2U0RsUSIsIm1hYyI6ImUzOTA4Zjk5OTQ3NDdjZmRmNTE3YmU3M2NmMzM4ZDBjMjA5YjBjNjFmNmE4YjFiNzA2YmJiYjEzZTYxMGU4YzEifQ%3D%3D; expires=Sun, 12-Jul-2020 22:13:33 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; samesite=lax
set-cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImFtT1JqL3dmd1hwcE5sMWk5c3pCWHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidHk2K21TN2RUSEtFbXJKRis5endtY0lwT25pdllxOHpvUDg3NDh3RmdSNUhTdGI2cnpTbWIyUmw2NmJ1bXp3diIsIm1hYyI6Ijc1ODNmYjJlOTBlNTMzYjVmZGUxM2FiYWFkYzc1MGE0YjQ3Njc3YjEyNzJmMWY5NWJjN2FiNWY3NDdjMjk1NGYifQ%3D%3D; expires=Sun, 12-Jul-2020 22:13:33 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax
```

When a OK statuscode is triggered then http://localhost:3000/auth/api/user should respond correctly but it does not;
Request:

```
Authorization: 204
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: auth.strategy=laravelSanctum; auth._token_expiration.laravelSanctum=false; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IitnbFNyUncvZzlSVUxUc0pYbU9pZWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVW8vM3RaR0d4eDRWaUc1WENUVndMK0F4K0JJdmpGcTEzNUhTcjZWTk8zb3BjQlNiVXh4d3lEVE45OWM2U0RsUSIsIm1hYyI6ImUzOTA4Zjk5OTQ3NDdjZmRmNTE3YmU3M2NmMzM4ZDBjMjA5YjBjNjFmNmE4YjFiNzA2YmJiYjEzZTYxMGU4YzEifQ%3D%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImFtT1JqL3dmd1hwcE5sMWk5c3pCWHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidHk2K21TN2RUSEtFbXJKRis5endtY0lwT25pdllxOHpvUDg3NDh3RmdSNUhTdGI2cnpTbWIyUmw2NmJ1bXp3diIsIm1hYyI6Ijc1ODNmYjJlOTBlNTMzYjVmZGUxM2FiYWFkYzc1MGE0YjQ3Njc3YjEyNzJmMWY5NWJjN2FiNWY3NDdjMjk1NGYifQ%3D%3D; auth._token.laravelSanctum=204
Host: localhost:3000
```

Response:

```
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: 
cache-control: no-cache, private
connection: close
content-type: application/json
date: Sun, 12 Jul 2020 20:13:33 GMT, Sun, 12 Jul 2020 20:13:33 GMT
host: localhost:8000
phpdebugbar-id: Xc04736bfc1d9d6354be969c4e921b568
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
vary: Origin
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.8
```

Now running through Nuxt-Proxy btw.